# How to get previous day via SQLite in Swift

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite table with a number of dates. I would like to execute a query to select those records where the Date is the previous date. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL FROM (SpentAmount) Where Date ='\(Date().yesterday)'"
```

and output is : `'2018-07-02 05:43:16 +0000'`

But I want only date and this format: `'02-07-2018'`.

And I m trying This : SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL FROM SpentAmount WHERE Date = DATE('now', '-1 days');

but this Query  give me no result

This is my database [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrPWU.png) 
but when i execute the query then give me this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLG5P.png)

Comment: Previous date to what?  Yesterday, or the previous date to some other date?

Comment: How are you storing your dates?  Are you storing them as `02-07-2018` ?

Comment: Yes this is my Date Format 02.07.2018

Comment: And is that July 2nd or February 27th? Not a good format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target yesterday (i.e. the date before today), then use `DATE('now', '-1 days')`:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL
FROM SpentAmount
WHERE Date = STRFTIME('%d.%m.%Y', DATE('now', '-1 days'));
```

As a general comment, your current date format is very non ideal.  It will be very hard to sort your table by date.  Instead, you should *always* store your date information in ISO format with SQLite, i.e. use `2018-07-02`, *not* `02-07-2018`.

Comment: This should work on date but If needed in exact '02-07-2018' format, we can use STRFTIME like STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', DATE('now', '-1 days'))

Comment: Updated Question Please check

Comment: @CRDave It looks like you were right.  Thanks for commenting, I appreciate that.

Comment: Thank You @TimBiegeleisen This query Give me properly Result Thank you again Senior

Comment: @CRDave also Thank you Senior